# Looping through a json file in hdfs to display multiple iterative values for a Key using bash/unix

Tags: json, bash

I have hdfs path of a json file and I need to read the contents of the  multiple objects in the file, and display the different values for a particular key.

Tried to grep the key and value in json file but cannot move

```
hdfs dfs -cat /data/bin/sample.json | grep -i -m1 -oP "transactionKey"\s*:\s*"\K[^"]+
```

Sample json of input file:

```
{"name":"","transactionkey":"1234",......}
{"name":"","transactionkey":"1245",......}
{"name":"","transactionkey":"1256",......}
```

Expected is to display the values for transaction key in the iterative

Comment: jq functionality is not provided      example :  json file content example : 

{"name":"","transactionkey":"1234",......}
{"name":"","transactionkey":"1245",......}
{"name":"","transactionkey":"1256",......}

Comment: Tried to edit for grammar and code markdown, combine all available info into question body - but more information is needed. Some sample output for what you're trying to achieve would go a long way.